# LINQ to SQL запрос по строковым параметрам

Tags: c#, entity-framework

дано: EF Core 1.0.1 и следующие классы:

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId {get;set;}
   public string Login {get;set;}
   public string Password {get;set;}
}

public class DataContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

в следующем коде

```
Datacontext dbcon = new DataContext();
var users = from p in dbcon.Users where p.Login=="login1" && 
p.Password=="pass1" select p;
int number = users.Count();
```

возникает ошибка

> InvalidOperationException: The operands for operator 'Equal' do not
>   match the parameters of method 'op_Equality'.

почему так происходит? что нужно сделать?
полное описание исключения:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The operands for operator 'Equal'
>   do not match the parameters of method 'op_Equality'.
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetMethodBasedBinaryOperator(ExpressionType
>   binaryType, Expression left, Expression right, MethodInfo method,
>   Boolean liftToNull)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Equal(Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull, MethodInfo method)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType binaryType, Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull,
>   MethodInfo method, LambdaExpression conversion)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.NavigationRewritingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression
>   node)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.NavigationRewritingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression
>   node)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>          at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.WhereClause.TransformExpressions(Func`2
>   transformation)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.NavigationRewritingExpressionVisitor.NavigationRewritingQueryModelVisitor.VisitWhereClause(WhereClause
>   whereClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
>          at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1
>   bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
>          at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.NavigationRewritingExpressionVisitor.Rewrite(QueryModel
>   queryModel, QueryModel parentQueryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.OptimizeQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel
>   queryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](Expression
>   query, INodeTypeProvider nodeTypeProvider, IDatabase database, ILogger
>   logger, Type contextType)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<CompileQuery>b__0()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object
>   cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   query)
>          at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>          at SolidCRMCore.Startup.<>c.<b__2_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\ib\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\SolidCRMCore\SolidCRMCore\Startup.cs:line 78
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: `var users = db.Users.Where(x=>x.Login == "login1" && x.Password == "pass1").ToList();` IMHO конечно, но лямбда синтаксис в некоторых случаях читается более легче

Comment: форма LINQ не имеет значения. ошибка происходит при попытке проверить условия на строковых полях

Comment: В текущем виде оно не компилируется (нет свойства Users)

Comment: Попробуйте создать новую БД средствами EF. Ошибка повторится или пропадет?

Comment: Да, и приложите к вопросу, пожалуйста, полный текст исключения (вместе с трассировкой стека!) - без него получается гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: базу пересоздавал. добавил полный текст исключения

Answer (score 0):

вот так:

```
 var users = con.Users.Where(p => p.Login.Equals(login)&&p.Password.Equals(password));
```

работает, хотя первоначальный вопрос, куда копать, остается открытым

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости, это ошибка EF Core на этапе оптимизации запроса. Попробуйте использовать другую версию библиотеки.

Если по какой-то причине обновиться нет возможности - следует использовать Workaround с вызовом метода Equals:

```
var users = from p in dbcon.Users where p.Login.Equals(login) && p.Password.Equals(password) select p;
```

PS если на последней версии библиотеки ошибка остается - ей самое место [на гитхабе](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues), в списке багов

Comment: так тоже не работает. но работает dbcon.Users.Where(p => p.Login.Equals(login)&&p.Password.Equals(password));

Comment: @user242389 Именно так? Не работают константы? Два раза странно...

Comment: @user242389 а что с новой версией? 1.0.1 - это довольно старая версия...

Comment: не в константах дело. дело в применении .were()

Comment: @user242389 нет, с этой стороны проблемы быть не может в принципе. Компилятор генерирует абсолютно одинаковый код для этих двух вариантов.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, стоит сделать так:

```
        DataContext dbcon = new DataContext(); // обрати внимание на эту строку, у тебя написано Datacontext вместо DataContext
        var users = from p in dbcon.Users
                    where p.Login.Equals("login1") &&
                       p.Password.Equals("pass1")
                    select p;
        int number = users.Count();
```

И еще, как я понимаю, класс DataContext должен выглядеть так:

```
public class DataContext: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Call> Calls { get; set; }
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: первая строка - ошибся при перепечатывании, - не суть; в чем смысл Calls?

Comment: форма таки значения не имеет.... с Equals() та же ошибка

Comment: Calls используется в твоем примере. Я добавил свойство Users - с ним компилируется, и в данном примере работает. Это полный код?

Comment: не тот DbSet скопировал в пример. Да, конечно, там Users